# VB.NET - Best practice for handling complex SQL queries with optional parameters

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio, stored-procedures, optional-parameters

In my application, the user should have the option to browse for orders that have been placed by customers - and it should be possible to apply several filters to the search. That means that I need a dynamic SQL query where a variable amount of parameters can be applied.
In a standard WinForms application, what would be the best way to handle this?

So far I've been working with TableAdapters and stored procedures but as far as I know, I can not use these with optional parameters. So for example if a user wants to see all customer orders, this is no problem. But it should also be possible to say for example "Show all orders that have been placed in the last 2 weeks and where at least one product contains the word 'gift code'". So date and product-name would be optional parameters but if I leave those empty in a stored procedure, I get an error.

To fix this, I started building my own queries in a separate class using SqlCommands and parameters. I dynamically generate the commandText for each command depending on the parameters passed into the function, then I add parameters to the SqlCommand, execute it and loop through the SqlDataReader to build a list of items that I will return to my program.
For example (simplified):

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand With {.Connection = con}
cmd.commandText = "SELECT o.id, o.customer_name, o.date, p.productName FROM orders o JOIN order_positions p ON o.id = p.order_id WHERE o.date >= @pDate"
cmd.Parameters.Add("@pDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = searchDate
Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
Dim lstOrderItems As New List(Of OrderDisplayItem)
while reader.read
  dim orderId as Integer = reader.Item(0)
  dim customerName as String = reader.Item(1)
  dim date as Date = reader.Item(2)
  dim productName as String = reader.Item(3)
  lstOrderItems.add(New OrderDisplayItem With{.id = orderId, .customerName = customerName, .date = date, .productName = productName})
End While
return lstOrderItems
```

Now obviously this is just to show how I proceed. In reality, I have to create additional loops because one order might contain one or multiple products etc.

My question would be: is this the right way to handle this? It feels like this whole class will grow really big because I have other queries too like looking up invoices, store sales and so on - and for every query I have to write these reader loops which I would have to modify all over again if a slight thing in my database changes.
Is it really not possible to handle this within Visual Studio tableAdapters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> That means that I need a dynamic SQL query where a variable amount of parameters can be applied.

No it doesn't. You can use a single query with a single set of parameters and simply provide NULL for those parameters you want to ignore if you structure your SQL like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE (@Column1 IS NULL OR Column1 = @Column1)
AND (@Column2 IS NULL OR Column2 = @Column2)
```

Your VB code might then look something like this:

```vb
Using connection As New SqlConnection("connection string here"),
      command As New SqlCommand(query, connection)
    command.Parameters.Add("@Column1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = If(TextBox1.TextLength = 0, CObj(DBNull.Value), TextBox1.Text)
    command.Parameters.Add("@Column2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = If(TextBox2.TextLength = 0, CObj(DBNull.Value), TextBox2.Text)

    '...
End Using
```

When you provide NULL for a parameter, that effectively matches every record and that parameter is effectively ignored. You can do that with as many parameters as you like of whatever data type that you like.

Comment: Thanks, that's very useful. I've been dealing with this problem for 2 days now and couldn't find a comparable solution anywhere.
So I assume I don't have to feel bad for not using tableAdapters then, right?

Comment: Whether you use a typed `DataSet` and the associated table adapters is irrelevant. You can build queries like that either way.